# MySQL command line issue - ambiguous option --s

Tags: mysql, command-line

I'm getting the error below everytime I run a mysql or mysqladmin
command - even mysql --help!!

ambiguous option '--s' (set-variable, shutdown_timeout)

(The daemon is fine)

Any ideas?

Thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `~/.my.cnf`

That's an oft-forgotten place where options live.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I know this is an old thread, but it might help someone. I had a similar problem where it complained of mysql: ambiguous option '--d' (debug, delimiter). This was due to a typo in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file.